# UITabBarController not working on iphone 5 simulator and I am using xib so no mainwindow.xib

Tags: ios, ios6, uitabbarcontroller, iphone-5

I have added code to make a tabbar application with navigation features.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization




        ChatVC *objChatVC = [[ChatVC alloc]init];
        UpdateMeContactVC *objUpdateMeContact = [[UpdateMeContactVC alloc]init];
        cardsVC *objCardsVC = [[cardsVC alloc]init];
        settingVC *objSettingVC = [[settingVC alloc]init];
        NotificationVC *objNotificationVC = [[NotificationVC alloc]init];

        self.objNavConChat = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:objChatVC];
        self.objNavConContact = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:objUpdateMeContact];
        self.objNavConCards = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:objCardsVC];
        self.objNavConNotification = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:objNotificationVC];
        self.objNavConSetting = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:objSettingVC];
        self.objTabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];

        self.objNavConChat.title = @"Chat";
        self.objNavConContact.title = @"Contacts";
        self.objNavConCards.title = @"Cards";
        self.objNavConNotification.title = @"Notification";
        self.objNavConSetting.title = @"Setting";

        self.objNavConChat.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"online_chat.png"];
        self.objNavConCards.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"card.png"];
        self.objNavConContact.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"contact.png"];
        self.objNavConNotification.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"notification.png"];
        self.objNavConSetting.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"settings.png"];


        objTabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:objNavConChat,objNavConCards,objNavConContact,objNavConNotification,objNavConSetting, nil];
        objTabBarController.selectedIndex=2;
        [self.view addSubview:self.objTabBarController.view];





    }
    return self;
}
```

and in the updatemecontact i am using a tableviewon scrollview
and my xib is 3.5 inch but when i run program the tabbar doesn't work.I cant select on tabbar any option.

Answer (score 8):

Go to the MainWindow.xib, select the Window object and check the "Full Screen at Launch".

[image]

Comment: i am not using storyboard so there is no mainwindow.xib

Comment: can i code it manully I didn't found any answers regarding this

Comment: Make sure that key window has proper size. Workaround is to set proper frame: [window setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]].